# Cron job fails to send email

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to create a Cron job to run a php command that sends out a daily email.

**NOTE:  Security functionality to make sure only the server can request the email will be added once this is working.

******UPDATE: combined all of the php files into one (daily_email.php) in order to eliminate path concerns.

Cron job:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/server/mysite.com/php/daily_email.php
```

daily_email.php:

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "*********";
    $password = "*********";
    $dbname = "********";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ACTIVE = 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            .......                
        }
    } else {

    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

The functionality is fine when loading daily_email.php in a brownser.

The Cron job returns:
No database selected

The php file is set to 775 permission.  Does the database need some sort of permission set for the Cron job?

Comment: Try using absolute paths for both includes. It’s a common problem to have code break in cronjobs because of relative paths. Also, you’re missing an underscore in your `public function __construct()` method

Comment: What's in `db_connect.php`? **Please make sure to redact all connection details, including user name, password, host, and port.**

Comment: added db_connect.php code and made sure all files had absolute paths.

Comment: You’re using the wrong constants. You define `MASTER_*`, but don’t use that prefix when retrieving the value.

Comment: You could change your cron to `cd /home/server/mysite.com/php; /usr/bin/php /home/server/mysite.com/php/daily_email.php` also `DB_Functions` is missing a `_` in the construct.

Comment: @ishegg Sorry,  I pulled the constants from the wrong file.  I have a master database and a database for each client.

Comment: Combined all the php files into one in order to eliminate absolute path concerns.  The query runs when loading the file in a browser, but throws the connection error for the cron

Comment: I found the bug and it was totally unrelated to the question above.  I thank all of you for your time and effort to help